# Cannot start Azure stream analytics from azure automation run book?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-stream-analytics, azure-automation

When I'm trying to start Azure stream analytics from power or power shell runbook from azure automation

Here the code that I have used to start power shell

Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -ResourceGroupName 'RealTimeAnalytics' -Name 'SQLCDCProcessor'

Here the code that I'm using in my run book.

```
$ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
Connect-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose
Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -Name SQLCDCProcessor -ResourceGroupName RealTimeAnalytics
```

when I'm running, the following code only

```
 Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -Name SQLCDCProcessor -ResourceGroupName RealTimeAnalytics
```

I'm getting the out put as false

But when I'm running all the lines of code I'm getting the following error.

```
Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob : The 'Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob' command was found in the module 'Az.StreamAnalytics', but the module could not be loaded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should be caused by you did not install the `Az.StreamAnalytics` powershell module.

Naviagte to your automation account in the portal -> `Modules` -> `Browse Gallery` -> search for `Az.StreamAnalytics` module -> `Import`. Then try again after import completed, it should work fine.

**Update**:

In your script, you use the old AzureRm command `Connect-AzureRmAccount`, you need to use the `Connect-AzAccount`, also make sure you have imported the `Az.Accounts` module.

The sample works for me:

```
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"         

Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose

Start-AzStreamAnalyticsJob -Name "<jobname>" -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some IoT Hub actions are not supported by Azure PowerShell and must be completed using Azure CLI version 2.0.24 or later and the IoT extension for Azure CLI.

Install the Azure CLI and use `az extension add --name azure-cli-iot-ext` to install the IoT extension.

Comment: I have updated my code and installed the module I'm still getting some other error